# Active Directory retrieving group members on a group appears to be caught in an infinite loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, active-directory, infinite-loop

I have the following code below. Every time `directoryEntryGroupMembers.Properties["member"];` is called, it comes back with the same list. As a result, the while loop is stuck in an infinite loop. I suspect there is a problem with how the group is setup in AD itself as opposed to the code. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Note: I am aware of circular nested groups in our AD, but that has not caused a problem until now. So, I do not know if circular group nesting is the problem.

```
string strDirectoryEntryPath = null;
const int intIncrement = 1500; // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676302(v=vs.85).aspx
string strDsFilter = null;
string[] strDsProperties = null;
List<Guid> lstGroupMemberGuid = null;
DataTypeConverter objConverter = null;
DirectoryEntry directoryEntryGroupMembers = null;
SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = null;
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = null; 

objConverter = new DataTypeConverter();

lstGroupMemberGuid = new List<Guid>();

strDirectoryEntryPath = strActiveDirectoryHost + "/<GUID=" + strPropertyValue + ">";

directoryEntryGroupMembers = new DirectoryEntry(strDirectoryEntryPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

while (true)
{
    intCountIteration = intCountIteration + 1;

    var varGroupMemberDns = directoryEntryGroupMembers.Properties["member"];

    foreach(string strMemberDn in varGroupMemberDns)
    {
        if (dctObjectGuidDn.TryGetValue(strMemberDn, out Guid gidMemberGuid))
        {
            lstGroupMemberGuid.Add(gidMemberGuid);
        }
    }

    if (varGroupMemberDns.Count < intIncrement)
    {
        break;
    }

    directoryEntryGroupMembers.RefreshCache(new[] { string.Format("member;range={0}-*", lstGroupMemberGuid.Count) });
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing a variable that is not used in the `if` comparison?

Comment: @devlincarnate For testing. I wanted to see how many times the same list was coming back.

Comment: then what is `intIncrement` and where does it change?

Comment: @devlincarnate I apparently posted too little code. I have updated my post. The `intIncrement` is tied to a limit in Active Directory.

Comment: ok, so it's a static variable, which means `varGroupMemberDns.Count` shoulld change.  Have you stepped through that loop a few times to verify that it does indeed decrease in value ?

Comment: @devlincarnate That is why I am posting this - the count does not decrease and the same list keeps coming back. Hence, infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `varGroupMemberDns.Count` does not decrease, nor should it decrease.  What I believe you may want is to capture the count BEFORE the loop, and then decrease that count with each iteration.

```
var recordCount = varGroupMemberDns.Count;
while (true)
{
recordCount--;
...
  if (recordCount < intIncrement)
  {

  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a loop increment. Logically speaking, the loop runs in batches of 1,500. In the event that the current batch has a count that is less than 1,500, then processing is complete and there is no need to RefreshCache. The problem has gone away as the job now finishes. So, a change was made in AD and then corrected. Thank you for jumping in to try and help +1.